# Rewrite Rule with first and/or second subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like these URLs to be valid...

example.com/

example.com/results/

example.com/results/live/

example.com/results/live/123

example.com/results/ended/

live, ended, etc will always be alphabetic

123 will always be digits (page number value)

What I want to do is drop a php file into /results/ and pass "live" and "123" as two variables. I can get that working but if I omit the "/123" then I also want "/live" to continue to work. The problem is that the directory doesn't exist and doesn't contain two variables so it is rejected. I have tried chaining but couldn't get that to work.

A simplified htaccess file is shown below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine OnRewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^results/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /results/index.php?format=$1&pagenum=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
Options All -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404
```

I have dabbled with using "-" instead of a directory delimiter, same problem

In essence I happy with the way that any missing files or folders are currently being handled but I'd like to create an exception for this directory

If I can't figure this out another long winded option is to create actual subdirectories inside "/results/" with their own php file and manage the pagination as just one variable.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^results/([A-Za-z]+)/?(?:([0-9]+)/?|)$ /results/index.php?format=$1&pagenum=$2 [L]
```

The `(?:([0-9]+)/?|)` is a conditional look-ahead. It makes the last part (e.g. `/1234`) optional. If it's not there, `pagenum` will be blank.

Comment: Well done - that works! Do you know how to make the trailing slash optional so that example.com/results/live works the same as example.com/results/live/ as well

Comment: @Quotes Add a `?` after the slash: `^results/([A-Za-z]+)/?(?:([0-9]+)/?|)`

Comment: Unfortunately that generates a 500 Internal Server Error on example.com/results/live and example.com/results/live/ but other URLs still seem to be working

Comment: Just a thought (I don't know how) but could the trailing slash go into the conditional look ahead?

Comment: @Quotes It works fine for me as long as there's an `/results/index.php` file. Otherwise it loops.

Comment: I have a php file in the /results/ directory. To avoid unexpected issues I just have "hello" in paragraph tags in that file. Unfortunately I can't get the /? to work without getting a 500 error. I have also tried using {0,1} and expanded the character matching to be A-Za-z0-9 on both halves.

Comment: @Quotes uhh, ok, it seems I left out the `$` in the original regex. You need to make the begin/end bounded. See the edit